# Heat equation with harmonic source and Neumann boundary

Tags: parabolic-pde

Is there an analytic solution or series approach to the 2D time-dependent heat equation in a square with a harmonic source and Neumann boundary conditions $\nabla u.n=0$?

Comment: You can use separation of variables to get a series solution.

Comment: could you post a pointer to a reference doing so!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good reference on approaching this problem analytically:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/pde3d.pdf